# ¿Cómo envío un segundo message.setContent usando java mail?

Tags: java, android, app, javamail

Estoy usando java mail para enviar un correo desde mi aplicación android. ¿Cómo envío un segundo `message.setContent`?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Texto = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mensaje);
    Enviar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enviar);

    Enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


            Properties propiedades = new Properties();

            propiedades.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.googlemail.com");
            propiedades.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");
            propiedades.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            propiedades.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
            propiedades.put("mail.smtp.port","465");

            try{

                session = Session.getDefaultInstance(propiedades, new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Correo,Contrasena);
                    }
                });

             if (session!=null)
                {
                    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Correo));
                    message.setSubject("Primera Prueba JAVA Mail");
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("lepanier.pruebas.ventas@gmail.com"));
                    message.setContent(Texto.getText().toString(),"text/html; charset=utf-8");

                    Transport.send(message);


                }



            }



            catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: ¿ Quieres añadir un adjunto o simplemente concatenar mas texto al final ?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que por lo que entiendo de la pregunta quieres enviar un segundo contenido que esta en otro textview o campo . En ese caso no hace falta enviar un segundo content , simplemente concatenando al primero lo que quieras enviar se completara al mensaje.

```
String msg1 = Texto.getText().toString();  // tu mensaje actual
String msg2 = ..... // segundo mensaje q quieres enviar.
message.setContent(msg1 + msg2,"text/html; charset=utf-8");
```